# Script 70(Permission Denied) and Script 5(Access Denied) error in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

We are using JavaScript,

when I open it through url ex:- http://exampletest/ it will give error as Script 5 & Script 70,

error appears at the following code block,(while debugging F12)

```js
httpOb.Open("GET", host + "sample.xml", false);
```

but, if I copy the code(rightclick->ViewSource) and save it to a html file and open it..ie from local computer, it will run.

please refer this link for my previous Question where I updated the code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465561/website-is-not-working-on-ie11-but-works-on-ie8

Please Help!!,
Sarva.

Comment: What's `httpOb` supposed to be?

Comment: It might be a CORS issue - is the "host" the same host (baseurl, port, protocol) that serves the website itself?